# vba code to add a command button in current sheet

Tags: excel, vba

What is the vba code to add a command  button on currentworksheet, then insert a code to run whenever that button is clicked?

advance thanks.

**Note**: the task for the command button click is : select workbook name `123`(which is already opend), select worksheet name `ABC` then select range `a123`.

Comment: The macro to be triggered by the button needs to be written ahead of time (unless you use some rather advanced methods). Why would you want to write the code at design time but add the button dynamically? If you need multiple copies of the button (say on different sheets) then the button can be copied easily enough (including via VBA) and the pasted button retains its link to the code.

Answer (score 0):

I have an example here to add buttons and assign macros to them.
[Create Buttons and assign macros to them](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QwCbxTfGhlI&feature=youtu.be)